# Does web.xml file differ for Tomcat and Jetty

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, jetty-9

We generally write a web.xml file for deploying our websites. The file generally contains the mappings for various Servlets present in the WEB-INF folder of the website. 
I have created a website and its web.xml file and deployed it in Apache Tomcat-9 server. 
Now, I want to deploy the same website into the Jetty-9 container. What changes do I need to make so that it works in Jetty as well?
Do I need to make any changes to the web.xml file?
Do I need to change the structure of the .war file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally no, the content of the web.xml file and the structure of a webapps (essentially `WEB-INF/` and `META-INF/` folders) are described in the Servlet specification, so all webapps should be able to be deployed as is in any servlet compliant container.

That being said, I have seen some case where the container asked to add some "proprietary" elements in web.xml, so your best bet is to test it.